# Rspec: how to test for yield self

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I'm using rspec 3.0.0.beta1. I have to test a method which yields `self`:

```
class Test
  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
```

This is a succesful test:

```
describe Test do
  context 'giving a block with one argument' do
    it 'yields self'
      expect { |b| described_class.new &b }.to yield_with_args described_class
    end
  end
end
```

But it only tests the object class, without testing the identity to `self`.

This is the closest (failing) test I wrote:

```
describe Test do
  context 'giving a block with one argument' do
    it 'yields itself'
      instance = nil
      expect { |b|
        instance = described_class.new &b
      }.to yield_with_args instance
    end
  end
end
```

It fails indeed, since that, at the time the last instance occurrence is evaluated it is `nil`, so it doesn't match with the instance inside the block evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `yield` matchers cannot be used directly in your situation. The simplest thing to do is a variation of your second code with a different matcher later.

```
describe Test do
  context 'giving a block with one argument' do
    it 'yields itself'
      yielded_instance = nil
      new_instance = described_class.new { |i| yielded_instance = i }
      expect(yielded_instance).to be new_instance
    end
  end
end
```